# Tf tree for multiple turtlebots

Tags: ros, transform, tf-prefix, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to run two turtlebots in a gazebo simulation. I'm wondering about the tf tree for the robots. This is what I get:
[image: image description]

Sometimes if I refresh this I get:
[image: image description]

so the wheel_right_link and wheel_left_link switch between tb3_0/robot_state_publisher and  tb3_1/robot_state_publisher.

The launch file I am using is an edited version of the gazebo_simulations file found here: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/master/turtlebot3_gazebo/launch/multi_turtlebot3.launch.

When running the unedited version you get the same tf tree, just that it the wheel links switch between tb3_0/robot_state_publisher, tb3_1/robot_state_publisher and tb3_2/robot_state_publisher.
Here is the tf tree for the unedited launch file:

[image: image description]

This is the launch file I'm using:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3"  default="tb3_0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3" default="tb3_1"/>

  <arg name="first_tb3_x_pos" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_y_pos" default="1.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_yaw"   default=" 1.57"/>

  <arg name="second_tb3_x_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_y_pos" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_yaw"   default=" 1.57"/>
  
 

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/custom_world2.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>  
  
  
    <!-- Start marker detector--> 
  <node name="aruco_detect" pkg="aruco_detect" type="aruco_detect">
    <param name="image_transport" value="compressed" />
    <param name="publish_images" value="true" />
    <param name="fiducial_len" value="0.15" />
    <param name="dictionary" value="0" />
    <param name="do_pose_estimation" value="true" />
    <param name="ignore_fiducials" value="" />
    <param name="fiducial_len_override" value="" />
    <remap from="/camera/compressed" to="/tb3_1/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed"/>
    <remap from="/camera_info" to="/tb3_1/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
  </node> 


  <group ns = "$(arg first_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg first_tb3)" />
    </node>
    
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg first_tb3) -x $(arg first_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg first_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg first_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg first_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg second_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg second_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg second_tb3) -x $(arg second_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg second_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg second_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg second_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

</launch>
```

and this is my world file:

```
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <world name='default'>
    <!-- A global light source -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>

    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    
        <!--
     <include>
      <uri>model://marker</uri>
    </include>
    -->
    
    
    <plugin name="ros_link_attacher_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_link_attacher.so" />
    
    <physics type="ode">
      <real_time_update_rate>1000.0</real_time_update_rate>
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
      <ode>
        <solver>
          <type>quick</type>
          <iters>150</iters>
          <precon_iters>0</precon_iters>
          <sor>1.400000</sor>
          <use_dynamic_moi_rescaling>1</use_dynamic_moi_rescaling>
        </solver>
        <constraints>
          <cfm>0.00001</cfm>
          <erp>0.2</erp>
          <contact_max_correcting_vel>2000.000000</contact_max_correcting_vel>
          <contact_surface_layer>0.01000</contact_surface_layer>
        </constraints>
      </ode>
    </physics>

    <!-- Load world -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://turtlebot3_square</uri>
    </include>

    <scene>
      <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
      <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
      <shadows>true</shadows>
    </scene>

    <gui fullscreen='0'>
      <camera name='user_camera'>
        <pose>0.0 0.0 17.0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
      </camera>
    </gui>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

The reason why I'm asking is because when I try using anything related to tf, for example rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree, I get spammed with warnings like these:

```
Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame wheel_right_link at time 705,364000 according to authority /tb3_1/robot_state_publisher
         at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

However, this warning does not show up when trying to use the unedited version of the launch file.
This question is related to a previous question: https://answers.ros.org/question/387984/tf_repeated_data-issue/

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I have been making gradual changes to the launch file. I started with the original and worked my way from there. First I removed one robot, making it so I only have 2. No warnings when running rqt.
Then I changed their positions so that one robot was behind the other. No warnings when running rqt.
Now I've changed the world from /worlds/turtlebot3_house.world to /worlds/empty_world.world. This is where I start getting warnings

After having worked my way from the original launch file to my own fully edited version I can with high certainty say that there is something in the two world files that is causing this issue. And checking this further it seems to have something to do with the house model:

```
   <!-- A turtlebot symbol -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://turtlebot3_house</uri>
    </include>
```

In the turtlebot3_house.world file. If this is removed, I get the warnings.

Edit 2:
I have now tested this with every world file available in the turtlebot3_gazebo repository: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/master/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds
But the only one I do not get warnings on is the turtlebot3_house.world file. And as previously mentioned, if the turtlebot3_house model is removed from the world file you start getting warnings.

Edit 3:
Still having issues, this time the warnings look a little different:

Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame base_footprint at time 284,759000 according to authority /gazebo
at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp

This time it's gazebo that's complaining, not the robot_state_publisher. The tf tree looks like this:

[image: image description]

Edit 4:
Because this issue has been partially solved and because the thread is getting messy a new question has been opened regarding the new warning:
https://answers.ros.org/question/388195/tf_repeated_data-warnings/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388044/tf-tree-for-multiple-turtlebots/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-10-06**:
The launch file looks correct. You've removed references to the 3rd turtlebot and added the aruco detector. My best guess now is that you're launching using an alternative version of the file from the one you're editing or something like that. If you know the original file works. Start with that and incrementally make changes until it stops working to isolate the problem.

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-06**:
Does the tf tree look correct for the unedited file? The thing that has me a little worried is if the file I'm working off is also not doing things correctly, and especially the wheel links switching between the different tb3s has me worried. But I will incrementally add changes and see what causes the issue as you said.

Edit:

I have been making gradual changes to the launch file. I started with the original and worked my way from there. If I use an empty world file I get the warnings, but if I use the turtlebot3_house file I don't get the warnings. In addition, removing the

```
   <!-- A turtlebot symbol -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://turtlebot3_house</uri>
    </include>
```

from the house file also gives the warnings. It seems that this model has to be in the world file or else you start getting warnings. More details in the edit on the post because of character constraints.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-06**:
Related discussions in [#360480](https://answers.ros.org/question/360480/multi-robot-simulation-on-gazebo/) seem to suggest that Noetic no longer supports `tf_prefix` (but since I haven't worked with Noetic much I can't verify). This would not explain why the one world file you mentioned does not give the warning... but would explain why, in most cases, the transforms from each robot are getting published to the same tf frame name.

but as a sanity check, you could consider the somewhat tedious task of either adding a `prefix` argument to each `joint name` field in the turtlebot's xacro file (e.g. `<joint name="$(arg prefix)*original_joint_name*" ...`. This would guarantee that the URDF passed to each `robot_state_publisher` have non-conflicting frame names and should avoid the clashing you're experiencing

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-06**:
Thank you for your answer, but it seems that the tf_prefix was recently added according to this: https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/169
So I can understand that the person in the related discussion would have a problem, but it does not explain why the problem is still occurring. But does the tf tree look reasonable to you?

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-06**:
As it was just merged 6 days ago, can you confirm that you are indeed using a version of `robot_state_publisher` that includes the fix (>=1.15.2)?

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-06**:
Of course, excuse me for sounding like a noob but how would I do that?

Edit:
Went into the package.xml of the robot_state_publisher package. It's:

```
  <version>1.15.0</version>
```

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-06**:
Assuming you're using ubuntu and you've installed `robot_state_publisher` using `apt`, then you can type `apt list ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher` in your terminal and it should tell you the version installed. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` should bring it up to date with the latest version, which [indeed looks like 1.15.2](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/noetic/distribution.yaml#L6688-L6703)

If you've built `robot_state_publisher` from source, then running `git rev-parse --short HEAD` in the package folder would tell you what commit you're currently using, but the simpler approach would be to just make sure you have the `noetic-devel` branch checked out and `git pull`

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-06**:
I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, but when I do `apt list ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher`, I get:

```
apt list ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher
Listing... Done
ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher/focal,now 1.15.0-1focal.20210922.194208 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Meaning that it did not update?

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-06**:
apologies - I was looking at `master` instead of the [releases](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/releases) on rosdistro. Looks like the last noetic sync [was 13 days ago](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-noetic-2021-09-27/22447), so the newest changes to `robot_state_publisher` have not yet been released as debians. The workaround would be to do a source install to use the newer version, while waiting for the next noetic sync (usually ever 2 weeks or so, so should be soon).

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-06**:
Alright, no problem. According to this the next sync should be in a week: https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-noetic-sync-2021-09-23/22378/2

How would I properly install robot_state_publisher from source?

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-06**:
Something to the tune of:

```
cd ~/my_workspace/src
git clone https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher.git -b noetic-devel
cd ~/my_workspace
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-06**:
Thank you so much! It seems to finally be working without warnings and the new tf tree has three seperate trees, one that branches out from tb3_0/base_footprint, one from tb3_1/base_footprint and one from odom.

Thank you for your time, and big thanks to tfoote too.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-06**:
For the sake of closing out this question, I've put the relevant details in an answer below. If you can accept it and close the question, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a while, ROS Noetic did not support the `tf_prefix` parameter so the respective `robot_state_publisher` nodes are publishing data to the same frame names. [PR 169](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/169) has added this functionality to Noetic, but, as of writing this question, has not made it into the debian release. You can install the latest source code version of this package with the following:

```
cd ~/my_workspace/src
git clone https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher.git -b noetic-devel
cd ~/my_workspace
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

Which should resolve the issue until the binary of version 1.15.2 is released

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-07**:
just to make it extra clear:

> Which should resolve the issue until the binary of version 1.15.2 is released

Switching back to the released binary version on his system is now the responsibility of @Roshan. This is not done automatically.

If you don't switch back, your version of `robot_state_publisher` will be "frozen" at whatever commit it was when you `git clone`d the repository and will never be updated (unless you take action yourself that is).

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-07**:
It seems the issue wasn't completely resolved, as when I tested today I started getting the warnings:

```
Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame base_footprint at time 284,759000 according to authority /gazebo
         at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

But I think the problem here is that there is only one odom topic in the tf tree and it's not connected to any of the robots. It is on its own and connected to base_footprint. This warning did not happen when I tested yesterday, despite the tf tree looking the same as it did yesterday.

The new tf tree will be shown in the original post.

Could this be because I did

```
cd ~/my_workspace/src
git clone https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher.git -b noetic-devel
```

and that there are other directories that might need to have the updated robot_state_publisher too?

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-07**:
Two potential thoughts come to mind:

1. you didn't get the issue yesterday because you appropriately sourced the workspace where the source version of `robot_state_publisher` was written. If you tried again in a new terminal without first running `source ~/my_workspace/devel/setup.bash`, then the binary install of `robot_state_publisher` is being used instead. Or maybe
2. I'm not sure if the [gazebo diff_drive_controller plugin](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle.gazebo.xacro#L64-L65) actually respects the ros namespace / tf prefix you set, so it could be that you would need to modify the plugin parameters for each turtlebot. I've had similar issues with plugins in ROS2, but can't say i've dog too far into it with ROS1

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-07**:
I think the sourcing is done correctly. I cd into the workspace, do `source devel/setup.bash` and launch the project through roslaunch. And then I open a new terminal, do `source devel/setup.bash` and launch rqt, and then get errors.

Not sure how I would do the 2nd option, but do you think the issue will be fixed in the next sync? Or maybe I'll have to go to Melodic instead.

Edit: Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-10-07**:
because this thread is getting a bit messy, I'd suggest opening a new question for this particular issue. I *believe* this is because the gazebo_ros_plugins are run by *gazebo server* and have no notion of the robot namespace specified in your launch file, unless you explicitly add `robotNamespace` to the part of the URDF that starts the plugin (e.g. in [here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle.gazebo.xacro#L61-L82)). Even if you do that, I'm not sure that the plugin will respond correctly. I can't see much in the [source code](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/noetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_diff_drive.cpp) that points to the plugin considering that tf_prefix or robotNamespace.... This is getting out of my area of knowledge though, so probably best starting a new question to prompt help from others

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-07**:
New question has been opened: https://answers.ros.org/question/388195/tf_repeated_data-warnings/